# Wordpress pages not working out correctly with HTML

Tags: pages

Hey all i am having some problems with finding out where wordpress saves my pages. I have a default theme selected and have added a few pages. However, the links to them seem to show up all the same (page.com/about, page.com/contact, etc etc). They all have the same content no matter what page i view (even though each page i set up has been published (saved) with different HTML in the box).

Where can i go to find out where its saving my HTML for each of these pages? I don't see a about.php, contact.php, etc in the theme directory so where is it getting that information (and better yet, where is it storing my HTML i add and publish for each of those pages?)

Thanks for your time!

David

Comment: WordPress stores post/page data in a MySQL database. Where are you adding HTML? Typically you just type and press publish.

Comment: im adding the HTML within the admin panel for each page (edit).

Comment: The HTML editor panel is only good for basic html.

Comment: Correct but whatever i put inside there **should** show up on that page, right? -- which it does not.

Comment: Yes, or when clicking "preview"

Comment: Doesnt show any changes made, Wyck. Same page for any page i choose to preview.

Comment: You should read Otto's primer on kses http://ottopress.com/2010/wp-quickie-kses/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress store your pages in mysql database

MySQL -> YOUR-DATABASE-NAME -> wp_posts / Your-Prefix_posts -> post_type

for pages wp_type=page & for posts wp_type=post

when you use wordpress visual editor it generates its own html but when you use HTML editors you can use your own HTML & works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress generates pages dynamically. I assume you've worked with a CMS that generates static files. Wordpress works off a template architecture.

Basically, you input content under the Pages menu, then it finds page.php within your template directory and conforms your data to that template on-the-fly. Check out the Theme Developers template file checklist for a description of what each file in your theme does.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Template_File_Checklist

To boil it down, Wordpress uses one template (page.php) for many database page entries.

A single post page uses single.php. Check out these files and see if you can target your content issues.